# Create a HashMap key from Callable

Tags: java

Lets say I have a callable and I want to use it as both the key and the data retriever in a cache.

```
Callable<SomeObject> callable = () => {
    return dataSource.getSomethingBig();
}

SomeObject result = storage.getFromCacheOrSource(callable);
```

Identical callables might be constructed elsewhere and be called through the cache. Thus I want to use the callable as the key in the cache to get it from there or fill the cache with the data (gotten through the callable) if it is not already in the cache.

```
public <T> T getFromCacheOrSource(Callable<T> callable) {
    String key = getKeyFromCallable(callable);
    if (cache.contains(key)) {
        return cache.get(key);
    }
    T data = callable.call();
    cache.put(key, data);
    return data;
}
```

How can I construct a key from the callable that will always be the same if the content of the callable is identical?

```
getKeyFromCallable(Callable<T> callable) {
     // What to do here to always return the same key for identical callables?
}
```

Comment: Why not pass id as a parameter: `getFromCache(String key, Callable<T> callable)` ?

Comment: Or you could try `String key = callable.hashCode()` and have a cache indexed by Integer rather than String.

Comment: @Benoit Using the hashCode of the callable as a key may not be such a good idea, as two equal Callables (equal in the sense that they produce the same value when called) are not guaranteed to return the same hashCode value.

Hampus, is there any reason you have to construct a key from your Callable? Could you not pass in a key as a parameter as Benoit suggested?

Comment: I cannot use `callable.hashCode()` as that would return unique hashCodes even though the content of the callable is the same.

Comment: Sure, it is possible to require a key but I'd rather not to avoid possible fatal runtime errors when developers mix up keys.

Comment: Then you could define an enum containing all possible keys, this would drastically reduce the risk that the developers use the wrong key.

Comment: It looks like you've gotten a catch 22 then, since you need the do `Callable.call()` to figure out if it's in the cache or not, but that is precisely the operation you're trying to avoid with your cache. Ultimately, you need to identify the Callable without relying on the value of the Callable itself. If you don't want to let callers pass in a key to identify the Callable, you could create the key yourself, and return it to the caller. When the caller next tries to retrieve the value, they will need to pass that same key to you so you can perform the lookup.

Comment: @DerekMok What is was hoping for was a way to serialise the method call itself (automatically name it) before ever calling it to check if it has been called before and then return from cache. In my current implementation I am using a key passed in by the developer and while that works it is suboptimal.